# Moving pandas pivot sub total to the bottom

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table

I have this data frame,

```
DistrictName         RegionName Value
Ashburton            Canterbury 451
Auckland City        Auckland   2459
Banks Peninsula      Canterbury 132
Buller               West Coast 361
Carterton            Wellington 75
Central Hawkes Bay   Hawkes Bay 67
Central Otago* Central Otago & Lakes District        Central Otago & Lakes District 190
Christchurch City    Canterbury 2046
Clutha               Otago  119
Dunedin City         Otago  312
```

I am trying to pivot this and have the values for each region & district, so doing this,

```
pivot_table(districtleveldatav1.head(10), values=['Value'],index=['RegionName'], 
                    columns=['DistrictName'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True).stack('DistrictName').drop('All', level=0)
```

gives me this,

[image]

I need to do two things here,

1. How can I have 'All' in DistrictName at the bottom of each region.? May be with label 'Total'
2. Is it possible to order the RegionName manually based on the custom order I have. Similarly the DistrictNames ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the columns are arranged in the alphabetical order of their names. `All` appears first because it starts with A and there are no other columns which appear before it when arranged in the alphabetical order.

To make the name `Total` instead of `All`, you could use the `margins_name` parameter as in

```
a.pivot_table(values=['Value'],index=['RegionName'], columns=['DistrictName'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True,margins_name="Total").stack('DistrictName').drop('Total', level=0)
```

after setting `margins=True`.

This will give

```
                                                                               Value
RegionName                     DistrictName
Auckland                       Auckland City                                  2459.0
                               Total                                          2459.0
Canterbury                     Ashburton                                       451.0
                               Banks Peninsula                                 132.0
                               Christchurch City                              2046.0
                               Total                                          2629.0
Central Otago & Lakes District Central Otago* Central Otago & Lakes District   190.0
                               Total                                           190.0
Hawkes Bay                     Central Hawkes Bay                               67.0
                               Total                                            67.0
Otago                          Clutha                                          119.0
                               Dunedin City                                    312.0
                               Total                                           431.0
Wellington                     Carterton                                        75.0
                               Total                                            75.0
West Coast                     Buller                                          361.0
                               Total                                           361.0
```

See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But some district names will start with letter w, so total goes in between, not in the bottom.

Comment: @ds_user Yeah, but I couldn't find a way to do that. Let's wait for someone to enlighten us.